# Chrome Extension get UI element from background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am starting to develop a chrome extension.
In my case I have the following manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "mY Notifier",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "myscript.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs","alarms"
    ]
}
```

So, as you can see i have a default popup html page and a background script.

I need a Background script because I need to update the icon badge from time to time when the Extension is enabled (not just if the user clicks on the icon). This works fine.

In my `popup.html` i have a couple of checkboxes. Now in my background script i want to check which of the checkboxes are enabled. How can i  do this? I cannot refer to my ui elements in `popup.html` using elementById. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access to `popup.html` from `myscript.js` because `popup.html` don't loaded before the click on a button.
You can call `functon` of `myscript.js` from `popup.html`:

```
popup.js code:

var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
bg.someFunction(stateOfCkeckboxes);
```

Comment: doh! ok don't know why i didn't thought of this. hower i managed to do it with message passing. Anything wrong with that?  except that it isn't really needed here?